# Windows Cant see 64 bit dll

Tags: c++, windows, dll, 32bit-64bit, ssp

So I have a SSP dll I am working (though I believe the type of dll is irrelevant).  anyway, the dll works great and it compiles without any errors for 32 and 64 bit architectures.

The 32-bit dll works perfectly on 32 bit boxes.  However, whenever I try to load the 64-bit dll on a 64 bit box, windows says "can not find the module specified.

I have checked the exports, and everything is fine on that front. But even trying to do a rundll32 on the dll, it says it can't find it.

so I am wondering if anyone else has seen this before, where windows seems to be unable to see your dll.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Run procmon and See where Windows searches for that dll and what the result Code is

Comment: Run `where <file>.dll` to check the 64-bits dll is in the path.

Comment: What does `SSP` mean in this context? The ssp tag certainly doesn't have a consistent usage.

Comment: Sorry was away on work for a while.  SSP refers to Security Support Providers. its a dll that affects windows authentication.

Answer (score 0):

1, you can use Dependency walker (http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to check whether the dll is referring anyother dlls (which may be missing).

2, for you troubleshooting, you can build the dll with /MT instead of /MD (as /MT will combine all dependent dlls into its own)

3, to make sure all the dlls(& 2nd lay ones) are in the lookup path, you can config PATH explicitly before using the dll (like SET PATH=d:\somefolder)

Comment: So i did some procmoning, and the results were sadly less the helpful. however it seems to be unable to see the manifest for the dll. now i dont recall explicitly making a manifest for the dll, just a source.def, and it works on 32-bit. And i can look at the exported functions.   i am looking into adding a manifest directly to the dll now.